# getting the hive meta-store url to use in other systems

Tags: hive

When I go into hive in command line, is there a way to get the hive metastore url that is being used?

I'm trying to connect another system to hive but can't seem to figure out what the metastore url is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the command.

```
hive> set hive.metastore.uris;
```

Here is the output

```
hive.metastore.uris=thrift://sandbox.hortonworks.com:9083
```

Using set you can get all hadoop and hive parameters that are being used when hive CLI is launched.